# Phonegap Zoom and android

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, zooming

i am using following code to zoom

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport"
    content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

and it is working fine. however when i click back button , zoom level of previous page is also zoomed. so for example i have zoom 2x on page 2 and i get back to page 1 it is also showing zoom as 2x. my requirement is when moving to another page zoom level should be default to 1.0.

Any help ?

Thanks
Brijesh

Comment: are you using jquery-mobile for managing the pages?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery-Mobile for managing the page transitions then you need to fire an event when the page has been rendered via jQuery Mobile. Try the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651776/jquery-mobile-rendering-problems-with-content-being-added-after-the-page-is-init):

It should help.

Comment: Hi RedDragonzz, i tried create as well has page refresh but it is not working , ideally i need to reset zoom and not to reload contents.