# jQuery Mobile styles being removed

Tags: jquery-mobile

I had code which I hardcoded...everything worked fine...then I swapped it out for dynamic updating:

```js
<script>
  var items = [];

  $.getJSON('initialize.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data["home"], function(key, val) {

      var tmp1 = '';
      var tmp2 = '';

      $.each(val["group"], function(key2, val2) {
        tmp1 += key2 + "/";
        tmp2 += val2 + "/";
      });

      items.push('<li><a href="#">'+key+' ('+tmp1.slice(0, -1)+')<br /><small>Completed '+tmp2.slice(0, -1)+' days ago</small><span class="ui-li-count">'+val["total"]+'</span></a></li>');
    });

    $("#temp").append(items.join(""));
  });      
</script>
```

Here is the container:

```html
    <ul id="temp" data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
      <!-- Populated dynamically -->
    </ul>
```

I have googled and tried the proposed solutions and none work:

[jQuery Mobile rendering problems with content being added after the page is initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651776/jquery-mobile-rendering-problems-with-content-being-added-after-the-page-is-init)

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

I've tried the above...I am curious to know why the above doesn't work...and what will and why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `listview('refresh')` after you add new items to your listview. So try

```js
$("#temp").append(items.join("")).listview("refresh");
```

instead of

```js
$("#temp").append(items.join(""));
```

> **[Updating lists](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html)**
>
> If you add items to a listview, **you'll need to call the refresh()
>   method** on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are
>   added.

Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/PFrwu/)

Comment: Thank you so much...I don't know how I missed that...I suppose frustration didn't help :) but thanks again