# jquery mobile css not applying on ajax (getJson) returned result

Tags: jquery, json, mobile, jquery-mobile, partial-page-refresh

Im using `$.getJSON` to fetch data from the server side to populate the data in my jquery mobile app. The problem Im having is that the json result that I fetch contains HTML tags. When I append this data to the div in app, the HTML tags are retained as they are Looks like this now

```
var menDet;
menDet="<ul><li>Offer
<ul>"+data+"</ul></li><ul>";

//data contains a <p> tag from the server side fetched data

$("#menu").html($(menDet));
$("#menu").listview("refresh");
```

From the Inspect element window, I just noticed the data value is getting wrapped within quotes and thats preventing the HTML from being applied to the HTML tags within the quotes !

Any ideas on how I can add them without them being wrapped in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the string in `$()` and get a jQuery object which constructs all of the HTML elements.

### Example

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TgTxc/) with jsFiddle.

#### HTML

```
<html>
    <div id="foo">
    </div>
</html>​
```

#### Javascript

```
var s = '<span><b>Hello</b> World</span>';
$('#foo').append($(s));
```

#### Result

```
<html>
    <div id="foo">
        <span>
            <b>Hello</b> World
        </span>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data perfectly from server in proper format as you required for appending then you can use

```
$("#yourlistview").listview('refresh'); or 

$("#yourlistview").listview('refresh', true);
```

Check the following link

> [JQM (jQueryMobile) problem with AJAX content listview('refresh') not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597036/jqm-jquerymobile-problem-with-ajax-content-listviewrefresh-not-working)